# Is it possible to separate tests on "Nightly builds"

Tags: protractor

I am wondering if tests can be separated so that my whole test suite will not run on every build but runs on nightly builds.

Is it possible to separate it this way?

I know to separate the tests on multi browser but unsure in this case.

---

Comment: What test runner do you use?

Comment: If you're using protractor, create a different config file which runs the specific tests on the nightly builds and have Jenkins pick up the specific file for its runs.

Comment: I use protractor and Browserstack.

Comment: Guys any suggestions for me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by passing two seperate sets of tests. It worked! Thanks